# Alternatives to zinc die cast (Zamak)

Tags: materials, metals, alloys

I am working for a small domestic home appliance manufacturer and we are looking at ways to reduce our appliance's carbon footprint.

Currently we use a lot of die-casted zinc-aluminum alloy (Zamak, usually), and we are wondering if there are more sustainable sources or processes to obtain a part with similar properties (i.e.: mechanical, weight ("heavy feeling")).  If the part is visible to the customer, then we typically paint the part which is also not very eco-friendly.

We are looking at aluminum or PCR-ABS with PVD coating, but aluminum prices are soaring and the PCR-ABS doesn't have the same robust feeling as a metal part.

Examples of similar parts are dishwasher door handles, oven handles, metal handles for electric kettles.

Comment: A more descriptive title would be " alternatives to zinc die cast". The zamaks' are basically zinc with a few pre-cent Al , and  possible Cu,  Pure zinc ( eg prime western) dissolves steel rapidly and the small alloy addition prevents the zinc from dissolving the steel injection dies. I very much doubt you will find a polymer anywhere close to the  7  density of zinc. Lead is the only  metal that is as cheap ( and not as strong).

Comment: Wood?  definitely renewable